# Track click data as % with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, click-tracking

I have a new feature which is exposed to *some* visitors to my website, depending on what they search for.

I want to know "if the feature is exposed to them, how many interact with it", ideally as a percentage.

I use GTM / GA but not sure how to get this relativity.. any ideas on how I could do it? Thanks

Comment: Does this feature have a unique ID?

Comment: It can have a unique ID, yes.

Comment: Is this feature a session wide feature? Or only particular to the page it appears on?

Comment: Specific to the page it appears on. 

Feature = x is actually just a 'filter' that is displayed when someone searches something specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can track this in many ways a simpler one would be to use an event. If you want it with visualization you can create an event based goal where the destination goal could be the event of interaction.

When an user is exposed with the new feature then fire an event. Configure this as an required event for the goal and destination event could be the interaction one.

After you get all the event counts then you can manipulate the data as you want.

Comment: so the destination event for the goal is the interaction with the feature so say... www.mywebsite.com/featureX 

And

the 'required event' is another event. Does that get setup in the 'goal' or separately and then visualized in GA?

Comment: You can use 'destination goal' in Google Analytics. When a user interact with your feature then fire an event and set an virtual pageview URL in the 'dp' parameter. This will act as an destination URL for your goal. And as an required step take www.mywebsite.com/featureX URL. Now, in Goal FunnelVisualization you will able to see how many users were exposed to feature and how many have used that.
ga('set', 'page', '/foo'); <- set this before firing the event and use www.mywebsite.com/foo as destination URL

Answer (score 0):

I think the step you are missing is the detection of the elements on page. To do this create a Custom JavaScript variable (lets call it 'Detect'):

```
function(){
return $('#FILTER_ID).length>0
}
```

This function looks for whether an element with the id FILTER_ID is present on page, and returns true or false.

From here you have a number of options.

1: Create an event on page-view if Detect equals true. Create an additional event for clicks on the element. Divide clicks events by pageview events and you have your interaction ratio.

2: Create a new hit level custom dimension. In your Pageview Tag, set this custom dimension to the value - Detect. Create an event for clicks on the element. Create a session segment where Detect equals true, then divide events by pageviews and you have your interaction ratio.